# Abstracting out function across value classes

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following code for value classes:

```
class Meters(val x: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(m: Meters): Meters = new Meters(x + m.x)
}

class Seconds(val x: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(s: Seconds): Seconds = new Seconds(x + s.x)
}
```

Is there any way for me to remove duplication of the "+" methods?
Something kind of like:

```
abstract class Units[T <: Units[T]](val x: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: T): T = T(x + other.x)
}
```

Except I can't inherit from value classes, and I definitely can't use `T` like a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [universal trait](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) with a type class, lets start defining the trait.

```
trait Sum[T <: Sum[T]] extends Any {
  val x: Int
  def +(other: T)(implicit evidence : FromInt[T]): T = evidence.fromInt(x + other.x)
}
```

Now we need a type class that tell us how to go from an integer to some type, lets define this and call it `FromInt`

```
 trait FromInt[T] {
  def fromInt(x: Int) : T
}
```

now lets define the `Meters` value class which is as simple as 
   
 `class Meters(val x :Int) extends AnyVal with Sum[Meters]`
 
and in the companion object we can provide an implicit value of the type class we defined.

```
object Meters{
  implicit val intConstructable : FromInt[Meters] = new FromInt[Meters] {
  override def fromInt(x: Int) = new Meters(x)
}
}
```

and now we can just do

```
val added = new Meters(2) + new Meters(3)
println(added.x)
```

Comment: From the linked documentation it appears that invoking a method from the universal trait will result in the value class being instantiated, which kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: Also, universal traits can only have method members, so `x: Int` won't compile unless it's a `def`.